# Why does second part of shebang have a priority?

Tags: python, shebang

I have python script running under different `python` executable than default one.

I have python executables both in `/usr/bin` and in `/mydir/mybins`.

If I run, I get:

```
$which python
/usr/bin/python
```

And if run `run.py`:

```
# cat run.py
#!/usr/bin/env /mydir/mybins/python

import os
import sys

print(u"Python executable: %s" % sys.executable)
print(u"From within Python PATH=%s" % os.environ[u"PATH"])
```

I get

```
# ./run.py
Python executable: /mydir/mybins/python
From within Python PATH=/usr/bin:... (and no /mydir/mybins)
```

Why? Is this by design? How can I make it use `/usr/bin/python` without changing the code?

Comment: Is the line `# cat run.py` part of the `run.py` file?

Comment: ... that is not how `#! /usr/bin/env` is intended to be used. Are you sure you can't change the shebang?

Comment: The correct shebang is `#!/usr/bin/env python`, because this will trigger the program `env` with the argument `python`.

Answer (score 5):

The `env` utility will execute its argument as a command.

If the argument is *not* given with a path, as in `env python`, the command will be looked up in `$PATH`.  This is usually what you want when using `env` in the `#!`-line of a script.

If the argument *is* given with a path, it will execute the command at that path.

In your `#!`-line, you execute a specific Python interpreter.  The `$PATH` will never be searched.  You might just as well have had

```
#!/mydir/mybins/python
```

as the `env` bit is in effect doing nothing.

To let the `$PATH` have effect, use

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

The first `python` executable found in `$PATH` will then be used.

An alternative is to bypass the `#!`-line completely by executing the script with an explicit interpreter on the command line:

```
$ python run.py
```

or,

```
$ /usr/bin/python run.py
```

Answer (score 0):

As Kusalananda has said you are specifically telling your script to use `/mydir/mybins/python`.  You want to know how to make it use `/usr/bin/python` without changing the code that points specifically to a different python?

You can accomplish this by removing `/mydir/mybins/python` and making a symlink to `/usr/bin/python` in its place.  I **strongly** do not recommend this but instead recommend you change the hashbang in your script.